# How can you store lists of objects in SQLite.net?

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite.net

Let us assume I have these two objects

```
class Customer {
   [PrimaryKey]
   public string id;
   [??????]
   public List<int> addresses;
}
```

and

```
class Address {
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int id;
     public string street;
     public int number;
}
```

Is there a way to use the SQLite.NET ORM to save the Customers object? cause I'm having a really hard time saving lists.

If there is no such way, is there some sort of event I can implement or method I can override so that when an object gets loaded code will trigger?

I was thinking something along the lines of adding [Ignore] above the list of addresses and when the event triggers I can use SQLite.net to load the ids of the addresses from another table

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: I don't believe SQLite.NET natively supports this. You have to manually query the DB to populate that list based on the IDs of the two models. However, I've used the [SQLite Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) library, which does what you want. I had great success in a WPF project using the library... I don't know how well it will work in Xamarin, but I suppose it's worth a look.

Comment: I use it with Xamarin and its fine, really great library!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963602/1107580)

You can do it with Text blobbed properties from the [SQLite-Net Extensions library](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions)

So for example in your Model class:

```
public class Customer 
{
   [PrimaryKey]
   public string id;
   [TextBlob("addressesBlobbed")]
   public List<int> addresses { get; set; }
   public string addressesBlobbed { get; set; } // serialized CoconutWaterBrands
}
```

from the documentation on Text blobbed properties:

> Text-blobbed properties are serialized into a text property when saved and deserialized when loaded. This allows storing simple objects in the same table in a single column.
>
> Text-blobbed properties have a small overhead of serializing and deserializing the objects and some limitations, but are the best way to store simple objects like List or Dictionary of basic types or simple relationships.
>   Text-blobbed properties require a declared string property where the serialized object is stored.
>
> Text-blobbed properties cannot have relationships to other objects nor inverse relationship to its parent.
>
> A JSON-based serializer is used if no other serializer has been specified using TextBlobOperations.SetTextSerializer method. To use the JSON serializer, a reference to Newtonsoft Json.Net library must be included in the project, also available as a NuGet package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, the text blobbed thing is not really what I was thinking of (initially my idea was to create a property that had a string of all the numbers seperated by | and having the setter split those numbers into a list, I didn't like that idea :)  ) but the whole sqlite-net extensions thing seems to contain ways to have one to many relations so that seems to work find for me, thank you

Comment: Yeah it can definitely do one to many relationships have a look at the Stocks/Valuation examples in the Docs in that link above

Comment: yup that's what I was checking out, let's hope this works with xamarin :) I'll accept your answer in a few minutes, won't let me do it so soon after posting the question

Comment: Ah cool no worries, defo works with xamarin made two apps with it.

Comment: Ah, it was from the link I shared, but it is no joke... You should always be hydrated when storing objects in SQLite 