# SQLite.net database with Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, sqlite.net

I have a problem with an SQLite database in my Xamarin.Forms PCL project. 
I have followed this example from Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

I've been using my own types to store data and it's worked Ok for simple custom types, but I've recently added `List<int>` and Attendance type to the custom object (Info).

Now when I try and create the object, i get the following errors:

Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
Don't know about MyApp.Attendance

Here is the init code:

```
readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;
database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
database.CreateTableAsync<UserPrefrences>().Wait();
database.CreateTableAsync<Attendance>().Wait();
database.CreateTableAsync<Info>().Wait();
```

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not store them by default like that. However there is sqlite-net-extensions which you can use to accomplish that. You can take a look about **sqlite-net-extensions** [here](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions).

Using this extension you will be able to do that with `TextBlob` property, something like this:

```
public class Address
{
     public string StreetName { get; set; }
     public string Number { get; set; }
     public string PostalCode { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [TextBlob("PhonesBlobbed")]
     public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

     [TextBlob("AddressesBlobbed")]
     public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

     public string PhonesBlobbed { get; set; } // serialized phone numbers
     public string AddressesBlobbed { get; set; } // serialized addresses
  }
```

More explanation about TextBlob from [url](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions).

> Text blobbed properties Text-blobbed properties are serialized into a text property when saved and deserialized when loaded. This allows
>   storing simple objects in the same table in a single column.
>
> Text-blobbed properties have a small overhead of serializing and
>   deserializing the objects and some limitations, but are the best way
>   to store simple objects like List or Dictionary of basic types or
>   simple relationships.
>
> Text-blobbed properties require a declared string property where the
>   serialized object is stored.

I just saw that there is also similar/same questions about this topic on StackOverflow already, so you can take a look at them also.

- [How can you store lists of objects in SQLite.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851232/how-can-you-store-lists-of-objects-in-sqlite-net)
- [Can I use a List of String in a class intended for SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663984/can-i-use-a-list-of-string-in-a-class-intended-for-sqlite/35963602#35963602)