# How to work with nested classes and lists in my table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm using [SQLite as a database](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/) and I have the following table, which works, when I create it:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

On creation of the table

```
database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>().Wait();
```

now I get some errors, if I want to include a nested object:

```
public class Test
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int AnotherID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class TodoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Todo.Test
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlType (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x001ad] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2080 
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlDecl (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2027 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.<CreateTable>m__0 (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:417 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].ToArray () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs:251 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:19 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00133] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:418 
   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<CreateTablesAsync>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x0002f] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLiteAsync.cs:108 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2157 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3189 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3054 
   at Todo.TodoItemDatabase..ctor (System.String dbPath) [0x00015] in C:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Todo\Todo\Data\TodoItemDatabase.cs:14 
   at Todo.App.get_Database () [0x0000e] in C:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Todo\Todo\App.cs:32 
   at Todo.TodoListPage+<OnAppearing>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0002c] in C:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Todo\Todo\Views\TodoListPage.xaml.cs:20 
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/448f54fd/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35 
   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/448f54fd/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/448f54fd/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-23/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:4ad81135-c1dd-4bba-bca3-4e991f58da69 (intptr,intptr)
 ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Todo.Test
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlType (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x001ad] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2080 
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlDecl (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2027 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.<CreateTable>m__0 (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:417 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].ToArray () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs:251 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:19 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00133] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:418 
   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<CreateTablesAsync>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x0002f] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLiteAsync.cs:108 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 <---
```

If I use a `List`

```
public class TodoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public List<string> Strings { get; set; }
}
```

I get

```
 UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlType (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x001ad] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2080 
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlDecl (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2027 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.<CreateTable>m__0 (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:417 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].ToArray () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs:251 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:19 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00133] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:418 
   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<CreateTablesAsync>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x0002f] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLiteAsync.cs:108 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2157 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3189 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3054 
   at Todo.TodoItemDatabase..ctor (System.String dbPath) [0x00015] in C:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Todo\Todo\Data\TodoItemDatabase.cs:14 
   at Todo.App.get_Database () [0x0000e] in C:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Todo\Todo\App.cs:32 
   at Todo.TodoListPage+<OnAppearing>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0002c] in C:\Users\some-user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Todo\Todo\Views\TodoListPage.xaml.cs:20 
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/448f54fd/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35 
   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/448f54fd/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/448f54fd/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-23/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:3ff99a1f-7842-4c41-b229-386570e8d19f (intptr,intptr)
 ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlType (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x001ad] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2080 
   at SQLite.Orm.SqlDecl (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:2027 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.<CreateTable>m__0 (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p) [0x00000] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:417 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].ToArray () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs:251 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:19 
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00133] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLite.cs:418 
   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<CreateTablesAsync>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x0002f] in /Users/fak/Dropbox/Projects/sqlite-net/src/SQLiteAsync.cs:108 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 <---
```

I'm using [SQLite-net Official Portable Library 1.3.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) . Do I have to use attributes like `PrimaryKey`, `ForeignKey` and so on? How? Or is the library only able to handle primitive data types?

The sample can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Todo/).

[This issue](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/553) states, that it should be possible to work with `List`, but not in the latest version. I tried to downgrade to 1.2.0 and 1.3.1 without success.

**Edit**

I installed [SQLiteNetExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions.Async/) and changed the sample code to

```
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Todo
{
    public class Test
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int AnotherID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TodoItem
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }
        [TextBlob("StringsBlobbed")]
        public List<string> Strings { get; set; }
        public string StringsBlobbed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I still get the same error.

**Edit 2**

I think there is a confusion between libraries. `SQLite-Net Extensions` depends on [SQLite.Net-PCL v. 3.1.1](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)). But Xamarin linked to the library [sqlite-net-pcl v. 1.3.3](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)).

`SQLite.Net-PCL` (*oysteinkrog*) is a fork of `sqlite-net-pcl` (*praeclarum*). It seems that the latter one is not compatible with `SQLite-Net Extensions`, which is what I need here. But does `SQLite.Net-PCL` support UWP? It hasn't been updated since 4 Jun 2016. And the most funny thing is that `SQLite-Net Extensions` links to [praeclarum](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions), which is wrong. I checked this via uninstalling all SQL Nuget packages and only installing `SQLite-Net Extensions`, which should trigger the required dependencies automatically. What can I do?

Comment: Don't discuss votes in your question. Anyway I'd guess you should read [ask] and include the actual error. "One or more errors occurred" is an AggregateException, which contains the actual exceptions that occurred in its `InnerExceptions` property. Those excepctions contain messages that you can further research, and don't forget to show your research in your question.

Comment: See for example [Can I use a List of String in a class intended for SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663984/can-i-use-a-list-of-string-in-a-class-intended-for-sqlite).

Comment: I tried to use `SQLiteNetExtensions`, but I get the same error for the list (see edited question). Shouldn't it be possible to work with `ForeignKey` to nest an object into an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to work with a nested `List` or `object` I need `SQLiteNetExtensions`. Because I'm using [another SQLite package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) than the [default dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) of `SQLiteNetExtensions` you have two options:

1. Manually add the project to your solution
   1.1. Download the source for `SQLiteNetExtensions`
   1.2. Add as project "SQLiteNetExtensions-PCL" to your solution
   1.3. Add this project as reference to all of your projects (portable, iOS, Droid, UWP)
2. [Install SQLiteNetExtensions 2.0.0-alpha2](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issues/107/supporting-the-wrong-sqlite-net-version)

Be aware if you have already installed some sql NuGet packages. Uninstall all of them first and then only install `SQLiteNetExtensions`. This will add all required dependencies for you.

For `List<string>` you can do:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }

    [TextBlob("StringsBlobbed")]
    public List<string> Strings { get; set; }
    public string StringsBlobbed { get; set; }
}
```

If you have other types of list you need a `[OneToMany]` relationship.

To work with objects you should be able [to do this](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions#markdown-header-one-to-one):

```
public class Test
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public string AnotherID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TodoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Test))]
    public string TestId { get; set; }

    [OneToOne]
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

A good guide how to work with `[OneToOne]` relationships (e.g. for objects) is [this here](http://www.dsibinski.pl/2017/05/sqlite-net-extensions-one-to-one-relationships/). For `[OneToMany]` look [here](http://www.dsibinski.pl/2017/05/sqlite-net-extensions-one-to-many-relationships/).

There are some more steps like creating the table, and retrieving and storing the data in a special way (`GetWithChildren`, `UpdateWithChildren`, ...). Also be aware of the [`CascadeOperations`](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions#markdown-header-cascade-read), which you will need if you have a multiple level hirarchy.

If you still get the error, read the debug log carefully. One has to make sure that `[ForeignKey]` and `[OneToOne]` is used on all classes, which use the object.

Comment: Can we still use "SQLiteNetExtensions" given that the project was last updated on 2015 and the nuget last update was on 2018?