# How can I Store Custom .Net Types in Sqlite Database ?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I want to store my custom types in sqlite database but when i do , it does not create table with an exception. For example, I want to store List in sqlite table, Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store List in SQL table. This is what tables are for. If you need a list you can retrieve it from DB and process it as a list in your application code. Storing lists breaks first normal form.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/408a372f1b465f67dffd0efe1b25c78ec4fdd022/readme.md?at=master) by TwinCoders.

It can store lists of string and other types by serialising the list. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963602/1107580) for how to store a list of strings.